# Correct grammar for "While speaking Cantontese with my mom, I accidentally said one half of a sentence in Mandarin and the other half in Cantonese."?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

The goal is to translate the following:

> Mandarin has sure enough affected my Cantonese. "While speaking
>   Cantontese with my mom, I accidentally said one half of a sentence in
>   Mandarin and the other half in Cantonese?

This translation feels awkward:

我國語果然有影響我的廣東話。今天我跟我媽媽講廣東話，我無意講的一個句子有一半國語也另外一半有廣東話。

What's the appropriate grammar for such a complex sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mandarin has sure enough affected my Cantonese. "While speaking Cantontese with my mom, I accidentally said one half of a sentence in Mandarin and the other half in Cantonese?
>
> 我國語果然有影響我的廣東話。今天我跟我媽媽講廣東話，我無意講的一個句子有一半國語也另外一半有廣東話。

我的国语果然会影响我的广东话。今天我跟我妈妈讲广东话时，我无意讲的一个句子，有一半是国语，另一半是广东话。

The way to express such a complex sentence is, split the phrases out.  For example

> I accidentally said one half of a sentence in Mandarin and the other half in Cantonese

is

“I said a sentence.” “The sentence is half Mandarin and half Cantonese.”

我说了一个句子，句子里一半是国语另一半是广东话。

Though yours is good enough to understand, personally I would suggest following translation:

我的粤语（表达）的确被国语所影响。跟我妈说粤语时，我无意间说出了国语粤语参半的一句话。

Comment: thanks so much! is 参半 used often in cantonese as well as mandarin?

Comment: @Crashalot usually 参半 is in mandarin, but also seen in Cantonese.

Comment: In daily Mandarin, we would prefer to use 掺杂、混搭、杂糅 instead of 参半, which sounds more like written language.

Comment: @HarrySummer Right. But the major advantage of 参半 to other alternatives is, the conciseness of “一半是甲另一半是乙”.